# Insomnia gives longer String than retrofit

Tags: retrofit

I am making a request to my back-end server
insomnia gives right string : dT8d0XzxSaSNqErV4dPs5i: APA91bFOIAgXsu_YRw91PYZw1JdtBDZfeR8HZRn6jYa3f-ewaFYZ77weK8kEjrKexPkg0FFBfCSJCJDJSJGZZZGZZGZZZGZZGZZDGZZZGZZDGZZZGZZDGWG1

But retrofit somehow cuts the token off and gives me only 44 character string with that request
dT8d0XzxSaSNqErV4dPs5i: APA91bFOIAgXsu_YRw91

What might be wrong?

The data must return the same keys.

I am ensured that my endpoints are the same.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventTu(response));
}
```

Comment: Before passing `response` object to `EventTu` constructor, use `Log.i("TAG", response.body())` and check if it's returing full string or half. If it's the same result, please [edit] the question and post `EventTu` code here.

Comment: i point out that string is removed after : in the responseString. Maybe it references to object?